# How do I keep a websocket server running, even after I close the SSH terminal?

Tags: php, ssh, ratchet

So, I am using Ratchet with PHP, and have currently uploaded a successful websocket example to my server.

It works after I go to SSH, and then just manually run "php bin/chat-server.php".

What I was wondering is that, in a commercial situation, how do I keep the chat server running?

Thanks.

Comment: This tutorial shows a really cool way of turning the WebSocket into a *nix Service to make it persist even when you close your SSH connection.  http://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a daemon.

If you are using symfony2, you can use the [Process Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html).

```
// in your server start command
$process = new Process('/usr/bin/php bin/chat-server.php');
$process->start();
sleep(1);
if ($process->isRunning()) {
    echo "Server started.\n";
} else {
    echo $process->getErrorOutput();
}

// in your server stop command
$process = new Process('ps ax | grep bin/chat-server.php');
$process->run();
$output = $process->getOutput();
$lines = preg_split('/\n/', $output);
// kill everything (there can be multiple processes if they are spawned)
$stopped = False;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $ar = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
    if (in_array('/usr/bin/php', $ar)
        and in_array('bin/chat-server.php', $ar)) {
        $pid = (int) $ar[0];
        posix_kill($pid, SIGKILL);
        $stopped = True;
    }
}
if ($stopped) {
    echo "Server stopped.\n";
} else {
    echo "Server not found. Are you sure it's running?\n";
}
```

If you are using native PHP, never fear, [`popen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) is your friend!

```
// in your server start command
_ = popen('/usr/bin/php bin/chat-server.php', 'r');
echo "Server started.\n";

// in your server stop command
$output = array();
exec('ps ax | grep bin/chat-server.php', &$output);
$lines = preg_split('/\n/', $output);
// kill everything (there can be multiple processes if they are spawned)
$stopped = False;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $ar = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($line));
    if (in_array('/usr/bin/php', $ar)
        and in_array('bin/chat-server.php', $ar)) {
        $pid = (int) $ar[0];
        posix_kill($pid, SIGKILL);
        $stopped = True;
    }
}
if ($stopped) {
    echo "Server stopped.\n";
} else {
    echo "Server not found. Are you sure it's running?\n";
}
```

There are of course also other helpful PHP libraries for working with daemons. Googling "php daemon" will give you a lot of pointers.

Comment: @mattexx what do you mean `// in your server start command` ??

Comment: I've been trying this too here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489734/run-a-detached-endless-job-in-symfony. Process has a default timeout of 60 seconds which you can change `$process->setTimeout(3600);`. Other than that, the created process isn't detached from the current terminal. so it tends to be terminated once the terminal is closed. The same applies when running this during a user's request

Answer (score 1):

The ratchet documentation has a [deploy](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy) page. Did you checked it?

Old answer:
It may be a bad idea on a prod server (this is a personal assumption), but you can use the `screen` command to open a terminal, launch your daemon, then press Ctrl-A, Ctrl-D, and your terminal is still *alive*, opened in background. To reconnect to this terminal, connect back to your server and type `screen -r`.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial shows a really cool way of turning the WebSocket into a *nix Service to make it persist even when you close your SSH connection.

Basically you make a file `/etc/init/socket.conf` with the following contents

```
# Info
description "Runs the Web Socket"  
author      "Your Name Here"

# Events
start on startup  
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn  
respawn limit 20 5

# Run the script!
# Note, in this example, if your PHP script (the socket) returns
# the string "ERROR", the daemon will stop itself.
script  
    [ $(exec /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/socket.php) = 'ERROR' ] && ( stop; exit 1; )
end script
```

Blog Post:
http://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Uchiha answer has been updated to include the relavent content, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Not a bad answer - could be more of a comment, but thanks nonetheless! :D

Answer (score 1):

From the Ratchet [Deployment](http://socketo.me/docs/deploy) page:

if you are running Ubuntu, fallow these steps:

1. install supervisor like this:
   [Installing Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/installing.html)
2. configure ratchet webserver as a service program like this:
   [Supervisor Process Control | Supervisord Install & Usage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eX7D40y9qv8&list=LLGtnaod08m0ZISB9O8U92aQ)

making a conf file in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/.conf and fill the conf exmple code from Ratchet Deployment page:

```
[program:ratchet]
command                 = bash -c "ulimit -n 10000; exec /usr/bin/php /absolute/path/to/ratchet-server-file.php)"
process_name            = Ratchet
numprocs                = 1
autostart               = true
autorestart             = true
user                    = root
stdout_logfile          = ./logs/info.log
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 1MB
stderr_logfile          = ./logs/error.log
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 1MB
```

3. run the following comands:

   - `$ supervisorctl reread`
   - `$ supervisorctl update`
   - and finally check if your service is running: `$ supervisorctl`

these are all the steps that should be added in Ratched Deployment tutorial.. but this approach may not be the best..

Answer (score 0):

Start it in `/etc/rc.d/rc` for *nix servers. This should launch your PHP script whenever the server boots.

I don't actually know about how the industry does it, as I am just a programming/linux hobbyist and student right now, but that's the route I would go on a personal server.