# Run a detached endless job in Symfony

Tags: php, bash, symfony, websocket, symfony-process

- Symfony: 4.1
- PHP: 7.1

---

I have working websocket server using [Ratchet](https://medium.com/@nihon_rafy/create-a-websocket-server-with-symfony-and-ratchet-973a59e2df94). The websocket itself works fin. I can run it from the terminal using Symfony's [commands](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#creating-a-command)

```
php bin/console app:websocket:execute
```

I'm having trouble getting around some of these issues:

1. You need to dedicate a terminal to running this command
2. Most webhosting services don't give you access to the terminal
3. I want admins to be able to toggle the websocket server on and off
4. Admins aren't required to know what a terminal is

For issue 1, I try to use this "detaching" cheat, but it doesn't solve issue 2:

```
php bin/console app:websocket:execute > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

In order to tackle all four issues. I have tried using a process. but the issues with this approach is:

- `$process->run()` - running a process with `php bin/console` always ends in a timeout
- `$process-start()` - starting a process means it runs asynchronously, but it also means the process is terminated once the request ends, terminating my websocket server too.

Here is an example

```
$process = new Process("php bin/console");
$process->setWorkingDirectory(getcwd() . "/../");
$process->setTimeout(10);
$process->run(); // Stalls for 10 seconds, then throws timeout exception
$process-start(); // Doesn't stall, but terminates at end of request

// $process->run() ==== unreachable code
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}
```

I have tried creating a console application, and run the command from there. but the same issues as a process apply here.

```
$application = new Application($this->kernel);
$application->setAutoExit(false);

$input = new ArrayInput(array(
    'command' => 'app:websocket:execute'
));

try {
    $ob = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $ob);
    $output = $ob->fetch();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return null;
}
```

As a final resort, I tried a bundle called [DtcQueueBundle](https://github.com/mmucklo/DtcQueueBundle/blob/master/README.md), because it mentions the following:

> Ease of Use
>
> > - Kickoff background tasks with a line of code or two
> > - Easily add background worker services
> > - Turn any code into background task with a few lines

So I did what they asked, created a worker and tried to run it as a "background task"

```
use App\Ratchet\ForumUpdater;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class SocketWorker extends \Dtc\QueueBundle\Model\Worker
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    new ForumUpdater()
                )
            ),
            8080
        );

        $server->run();

        return "Websocket started";
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return "websocket-server";
    }
}
```

Their docs are the absolute worst! I even tried to dig into their code to start jobs from inside my controller. But I couldn't get it to run in a detached manner.

Whatever happens, I believe my command isn't running because it highjacks my PHP thread. I would like to know, is it possible to detach this endless process? Is it even possible to run two PHP instances together? I would think so!

Thanks for any help, sorry for the long post

Comment: If your host doesn't give you shell access they're for damn sure not going to let you run custom daemons/services, nor are they going to like you trying to fork off orphans for the same purpose. Get a VPS or better and write a system service definition for your daemon.

Comment: @Sammitch The host I'm using does allow `exec`, `shell_exec`, `proc_open` and things like that. I was hoping that would do the trick somehow

Comment: Can you run arbitrary commands so you can start a GNU screen session in detached mode and run your program in it?

Comment: @EmilyE. If I understand you correctly, you want me to run commands in a subshell? I believe this won't work either for the same reason `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` doesn't work. All processes in my terminal session are terminated once the user's request ends. This includes subshells.

Comment: @EmilyE. In case it would work. wouldn't it become increasingly difficult to track the running process? The goal here is to be able to do everything from within a symfony controller/service/command

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). it's like Expect but u can use sexpect with bash code. it can start a command on a pty in the background and still u have full control of it.

Comment: @pynexj that might solve the tracking problem, but this still wouldn't solve issue 2. `Most webhosting services don't give you access to the terminal`. good to know though!

Comment: @DerpyNerd Is there any solution you found or recommend?, I am in exactly same situation with ratchet socket

Comment: @MayankTiwari Hi, well... actually... yes and no. I couldn't run this in a terminal, because of the nature of terminals it would timeout or break for whatever reason. Plus not all web hosting services provide you with sufficient shell access to tinker. I eventually ended up using chronjobs or windows task manager - depending on what OS you're running. The upside is that you can configure tasks to restart should they fail